# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression with back to top button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im making my own wordpress theme. I almost completed it but I got one more little problem which I can't seem to figure out. I tried a couple things that previous posts suggested too but nope. I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://ericgraventein.nl/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/#top
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.js:1496)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.js:2113)
    at ga.select (jquery.js:2517)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.js:893)
    at m.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2733)
    at new m.fn.init (jquery.js:2850)
    at m (jquery.js:73)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:39)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
```

The error appears when this back to top button is pressed:

```
<!-- back to top -->
        <a id="mybutton" href="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/#top">

            <img class="backtotop" src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/images/backtotop.png" alt="backtotop">

        </a>\
```

This is from my .js file:

```
// BACK TO TOP
var isVisible = false;
$(function() 
{
    $('#mybutton').on('click', function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
    });
});
```

I tried wrapping '#mybutton' with the " " things but that didnt result in anything. Tried this because other posts would wrap the hashtag # with "#". Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I've also added this to my functions.php

```
function modify_jquery() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Comment: Halp pls, i really need a fix :(

Answer (score 0):

This mistake is because the jquery dont accept somer chart in thi case '/' and like you "https://ericgraventein.nl/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/#top" it have then throw this fix...
 i hope it can help you.

and sorry because my bad english